# How to convert this to lambda syntax?

Tags: c#, linq

```
List<string> phrases = new List<string>() { "an apple a day", "the quick brown fox" };
var words = from phrase in phrases from word in phrase.Split(' ') select word;
```

I want to do the same but following the lambda syntax, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried? Is there any particular bit of this you are having problems with? Have you looked at basic tutorials?

Comment: And the outcome should be one list with all words?

Comment: John Skeet's C# in Depth gives good explanations of how query syntax translates to lambdas https://www.manning.com/books/c-sharp-in-depth-third-edition

Answer (score 3):

You haven't really been clear what you are trying to accomplish by using a lambda expression, and I don't really know that your code lends itself to one. But here's one way you could include a lambda expression.

```
List<string> phrases = new List<string>() { "an apple a day", "the quick brown fox" };
var words = phrases.SelectMany(p => p.Split(' '));
```